# how do you prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n^2 +1}{n^2}\neq 1$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I'm trying to give a precise proof using the epsilon limit definition of a sequence that the sequence doesn't converge to $1$. I know how to solve this using the arithmetic of limits, but I need help understanding proof of the limit.

So far, I know that I begin with $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that  $$n > N \implies |\frac{2n^2 +1}{n^2} - 1| < \epsilon$$

if the limit is true but where do I go from here?

Comment: Hint: $(2n^2+1) / n^2 \ge 2$ for $\forall n$.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to show that the limit is not $1$, so you have to negate the definition of a limit. This means you want to show that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that there exist infinitely many $n$ such that
$$\left\vert \frac{2n^2 + 1}{n^2} - 1 \right\vert \geq \epsilon.$$
As suggested in the comments, $(2n^2 + 1)/n^2 \geq 2$ for every $n$. Therefore
$$\left\vert \frac{2n^2 + 1}{n^2} - 1 \right\vert \geq 1$$
for every $n$.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to show that it converges to $2$ and then use the fact that limits are unique.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We see that $$| \frac{2n^2 + 1}{n^2} - 2| = \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Now, let $N > \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$. Then for every $n \ge N$, we have $n > 1/\sqrt{\epsilon}$, and therefore$$| \frac{2n^2 + 1}{n^2} - 2| = 1/n^2 < \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}^2}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}} = \epsilon.$$
By definition, this means that the limit is $2$, and therefore it cannot possibly be $1$.